# Сортировка меток WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, tag

На WP-сайте есть вот такое облако меток:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас сортировка идёт по имени, а нужна по популярности (чтобы более жирные теги были первыми).

В файл `functions.php` своей темы я добавил

```
add_filter('widget_tag_cloud_args',function set_tag_cloud_args( $args ) {
    $args['orderby '] = 'count';
    $args['order '] = 'DESC';

    return $args;
});
```

Файл `category-template.php`:

```
$defaults = array(
        'smallest'   => 8,
        'largest'    => 22,
        'unit'       => 'pt',
        'number'     => 45,
        'format'     => 'flat',
        'separator'  => "\n",
        'orderby'    => 'count',
        'order'      => 'DESC',
        'exclude'    => '',
        'include'    => '',
        'link'       => 'view',
        'taxonomy'   => 'post_tag',
        'post_type'  => '',
        'echo'       => true,
        'show_count' => 0,
    );
```

Но это не привело к результату.